# Issue in redirecting with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, redirect, resttemplate

**Overview:**

The following code is responsible to call an external REST service. The external service redirects to a page.

```
restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/<endpoint address>",
                GET,
                new HttpEntity<String>(headers),
                String.class);
```

**Issue:**

The response backs as a pure html text which is wrong. 
The expected one is redirecting to the page that the external service has already been redirected to.

*Is there any way to handle that?

Comment: It depends on the underlying http library, do you know which you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
It's spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE

Comment: That's not the http library.  It's probably apache http or okhttp or some such.  Figure out what that is and take a look at configuring that.  It's lower level than spring.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using *HttpURLConnection* instead of *RestTemplate*:

```
HttpURLConnection con = getHttpURLConnection();

    try {
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.setRequestProperty(requestHeaderName, requestHeaderValue);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        con.getResponseCode();

        verifyResponseCode(con);

        String redirectPath = con.getURL().toString();
        return new RedirectView(redirectPath);

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
```

And in the getHttpURLConnection:

```
HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection() throws Exception {
    URL securedUrl = new URL("URL");
    return (HttpURLConnection) securedUrl.openConnection();
}
```

Now it works for me. 
The *con.getURL()* returns redirected URL from external service and now I can access to it.